# Strange "undefined index" error solved with type declaration

Tags: php

Figured out a strange (to me) undefined index error and wanted to share in case anyone else was banging their heads against the wall.

Short answer: Type casting the argument INTO a function made sure the array that got returned could be used in strings with no "undefined index" error.

Here's what happened: The code took a value from the URL ($params),
passed it into a function to get a big array of data back,
then put one of the elements of the array into a string.

```
$wid = $params[2] ?? null; // get id from URL parameter

$wk = \Workshops\get_workshop_info($wid); // get a big array

if (isset($wk['title'])) {
    $message = "The title of this workshop is: {$wk['title']}"; // no warning
}

$message = "The title of this workshop is: {$wk['title']}"; // undefined index?

print_r($wk);
```

I got an "undefined index" when I tried to include $wk['title'] in a string outside of an "isset" clause.

The output for print_r($wk) showed the 'title' index existing with a value.  (I edited out some of this array that had people's emails)

```
Array
(
    [id] => 425
    [title] => Sketch Writing
    [start] => 2021-11-07 17:00:00
    [end] => 2021-11-07 19:30:00
    [cost] => 225
    [capacity] => 8
    [notes] => A new WGIS sketch writing class for advanced sketch students and brand new students alike. If you’re an experienced writer, come hone your craft. Learn new sketch technique, new styles, new formats. If you’re brand new, come learn how to take your fun idea and turn it into a stageable, shootable, performable sketch. Great for improv students who want to transition into writing. Whatever your background- the focus will be on writing in your voice. Take the stuff that YOU find funny and turn it into a great script. This is an active writing class. You’ll leave with at least two complete sketches by the end of the five weeks! 
    [location_id] => 8
    [sold_out_late] => -1
    [when_public] => 1969-12-31 16:00:00
    [teacher_id] => 8
    [co_teacher_id] => 
    [reminder_sent] => 0
    [application] => 0
    [address] => 
    [city] => 
    [state] => 
    [zip] => 
    [place] => Online
    [lwhere] =>    
    [soldout] => 0
    [showstart] => Sun Nov 7 5pm (PDT)
    [showend] => 7:30pm (PDT)
    [when] => Sun Nov 7 5pm-7:30pm (PDT)
    [short_title] => Sketch Writing
    [costdisplay] => $225 USD
    [total_class_sessions] => 5
    [total_show_sessions] => 0
    [total_sessions] => 5
    [time_summary] => 5 classes
    [full_when] => Sun Nov 7 5pm-7:30pm (PDT)<br>
Sun Nov 14 5pm-7:30pm<br>
Sun Nov 21 5pm-7:30pm<br>
Sun Nov 28 5pm-7:30pm<br>
Sun Dec 5 5pm-7:30pm<br>

    [upcoming] => 1
    [actual_revenue] => 0
    [enrolled] => 5
    [waiting] => 0
    [dropped] => 0
    [applied] => 0
    [paid] => 0
    [open] => 3
)
```

The solution surprised me -- I had to explicitly cast the parameter I used in my function to be an int. This fixed everything:

```
$wid =  (int) ($params[2] ?? 0);
$wk = \Workshops\get_workshop_info($wid); // get a big array
```

PHP thought the argument $wid was a string. But the function get_workshop_info() assumed it was getting an int. There was no error thrown because I had not done any type declaration in get_workshop_info(). But passing in what PHP thought was a string got back an array that I just couldn't use without getting undefined index errors.

I put type declarations in all my function arguments after this.

This code is from a handmade huge MVC nightmare that I've created. I didn't even bother asking because there were just so many places that could be causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had to explicitly cast the parameter I used in my function to be an int. This fixed everything:

```
$wid =  (int) ($params[2] ?? 0);
$wk = \Workshops\get_workshop_info($wid); // get a big array
```

PHP thought the argument $wid was a string. But the function get_workshop_info() assumed it was getting an int. There was no error thrown because I had not done any type declaration in get_workshop_info(). But passing in what PHP thought was a string got back an array that I just couldn't use without getting undefined index errors.